# finding similar strings from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to implement a customers list in an application that I derive the DB from MySQL, 
Currently we would take the first and last name, dob, and phone number of said people.

To search for the customer we may enter a phone number and ideally it will find the person with the correct phone number - but I want to enter a fail-safe - lets say the previous representative entered the phone number slightly incorrect lets say the phone number is 7777777777 and the person accidentally types 7777077777 I would still want it to show up in query of course in order of relevance - so 7777777777 would be the preferred and top result.

```
Select * from Customers WHERE Pnumb Like....
```

would be what I would expect however I would not know how to implement that.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I can not find much (any) information on this online.

Comment: How about [soundex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)?

Comment: soundex only works on A-Z

Comment: full text search also ignores numbers

Comment: Have you tried to create 10 LIKE clauses replacing one position each time with an underscore?

Comment: I think the best solution to this problem is Levenshtein distance (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance‎).  You can google that to determine if there is an implementation in MySQL.